# Mysql query where relationship many to many contains all value of array at least

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, doctrine, relational-division

i try to make an SQL request to get all products contains an array of categories.
Products ==ManyToMany== Categories

I select categories id 11 and 197 and i need to find all products having both of these categories.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT p0_.id AS id_0,
  p0_.titre AS titre_1
FROM
  produit p0_
  LEFT JOIN produit_categorie_produit p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.produit_id
  LEFT JOIN categorie_produit c1_ ON c1_.id = p2_.categorie_produit_id  
WHERE
   c1_.id IN (197, 11)
ORDER BY
  titre_1 ASC
LIMIT
  12;
```

Here IN is a big probleme because i get product from one categorie and from others, but it's not what i want.
Im really lost here after many hours of test....
I'm using doctrine in symfony and that generate that sql request here is my doctrine query

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')->leftJoin('p.categories', 'c');
    $qb->addSelect('p.titre as titre');
    if ($value){
        $qb->andWhere('c in (:cat)')->setParameter('cat', $value );   
    }        
    return $qb->getQuery();
```

I removed some addSelect with no important informations.

Best regards

Comment: So your query is going to return all products in category 197 OR category 11.  Is it true that you want products in category 197 AND category 11?

Comment: Yeah, i want to get product in cattegory 197 AND 11 not OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure SQL, you would typically use `group by` and `having` to ensure that the products you select have both categories:

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.titre AS titre_1
FROM produit p0_
INNER JOIN produit_categorie_produit p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.produit_id
INNER JOIN categorie_produit c1_ ON c1_.id = p2_.categorie_produit_id  
WHERE c1_.id IN (197, 11)      -- any of the two categories
GROUP BY p0_.id, p0_.titre
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2            -- both match
ORDER BY titre_1
LIMIT 12;
```

If the same category may show up twice for a given product, then you would need `COUNT(DISTINCT c1_.id)` instead.

Note that I changed the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s, since that's what the query does anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that works ! I just convert it to DQL language for doctrine and it's perfect !